# iterate over json object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

i have a ko.observable in which i hold a json object with the structure:

```
{
"abc": {},
"zdc": {}
}
```

How can i iterate over this using foreach from knockout?

Till now, i've managed to iterate over the keys("abc","zdc"), but i don't know how to grab the value from the observable using the key.

Here is my code

```
 <div data-bind="foreach: { data: Object.keys(copyProgStats2()), as: 'item' }">
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <span data-bind="text: item"></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

where `copyProgStats2` is the ko.observable that holds the json obj.

It is important that i don't use observable arrays in this case, as it would make a lot more things harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do: `$parent.copyProgStats2()[item]`, take a look:

```js
function AppViewModel() {
    this.copyProgStats2 = ko.observable({
      "abc": 'cool',
      "zdc": 'good enough'
    });
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: { data: Object.keys(copyProgStats2()), as: 'item' }">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span data-bind="text: $parent.copyProgStats2()[item]"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Any but the simplest operations on your data are better done in the viewmodel, to keep your view from being complex and cluttered. A little auxiliary function can handle turning the observable object into an array suitable for `foreach`.

I added a delayed change to the object, so you can see that it will update in the view. I had to use `valueHasMutated` because the update I did wasn't something that an observable can notice.

```js
function AppViewModel() {
  this.copyProgStats2 = ko.observable({
    "abc": 'cool',
    "zdc": 'good enough'
  });
  this.toArray = function(observableObject) {
    var obj = observableObject();
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(Object.keys(obj), function(key) {
      return obj[key];
    });
  };
}
vm = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);

setTimeout(function() {
  vm.copyProgStats2().extra = 'new';
  vm.copyProgStats2.valueHasMutated();
}, 1500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: toArray(copyProgStats2)">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```